# where can i find a strong time picker and datepicker for momentjs and knockout

Tags: knockout.js, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker, momentjs

i am looking for a strong time picker and Datepicker for Momentjs and knockout most of the picker i have are just like this:

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-input-types-alternative

http://makingsense.github.io/moment-datepicker/

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

if possible using html5 inputs and working on firefox and ie 10

can anyone help me on that ?

Comment: The standard input type=time works for me with Knockout and Moment, as does the HTML5
, jQuery and Bootstrap date pickers.  What is wrong with using them?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with it i am working with html5 date and time input too but i was a crossbrowswer solution a came across this http://davidwalsh.name/html5-input-types-alternative but i am not sure about the performance so i am asking if there is a better solution for a big project

Comment: we use kendoUI. there is a good kendo-knockout library that helps with the inline bindings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this https://knockoutplus.codeplex.com/documentation

There is dataValue custom binding:

```
<input data-bind="dateValue: { value: dateValue, format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', lang: 'en' }" />
```

It depends on http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ but I plan to support also html5 input type when is supported and if not supported then use this date picker.